# Is my attempt at using normal approximation of binomial wrong?

Tags: normal-distribution

Suppose 80% of all drivers wear seat belts, and a SRS of 100 drivers were recorded. What is the probability that more than 75 of the selected drivers will be wearing a seatbelt?

Since n is large enough, I can say that the distribution of the sample mean ~ N(80, 4). Then look at z table for P((75-80)/4 < z), which gave me a probability of 0.1056. However, this is wrong, as the answer is 0.87. I'm just wondering how did I get such a massively different number?

Comment: Where does the 4 come from? Are you given the standard deviation or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Tyberius V(X) = npq = 16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You picked the wrong tail of the standard normal distribution, i.e., you looked up $P(Z < (75-80)/4)$. To get the desired probability you just subtract from $1$.

Note this gets you 0.8944, which is not the official answer. To get 0.87, you use the *continuity correction*, which means you calculate the probability that a $N(80,4)$ variable exceeds 75.5. Why 75.5? Remember you want the probability that *more than* 75 drivers wear a seat belt, which means 76 *or more*. The continuity correction imagines a block of unit width centered at the endpoint 76, which means the block starts at 75.5.

Performing the standardizing, this probability is $$P\left(Z > \frac{75.5-80}4\right) = P(Z > -1.125) = 0.8697.$$

Comment: Oh, so is this correction to account for the fact that the binomial is a discrete and normal is continuos, and for a continuos distribution equal and more than is just the same as equal, while for the discrete it's not??

Comment: @LtotheV Exactly! For discrete distributions the continuity correction gets you a better normal approximation.